# how to access and query partner related List in Account within Partner Community SQL

Tags: query

I am trying to connect a new account in partner community to a parent account in salesforce. I have looked few different ways but nothing works the only way so far that i have seen working is by using Partner , but I need to know how I can access or query Partner Related list

Comment: You are saying both Parent and Partner here, which is confusing me a little. Are you asking how to add an account to the Parent Account field or link an account under the Partner Related List? I believe both would require a trigger, but one would be more involved than the other.

Comment: @smckitrick Thank you for reply. In salesforce I create a partner community Account, and this account has few Partner User lets call it agent. The agents would login to partner and create customers account. Right now The customer account information will not be linked to the Agent account that he works for. Even using Parent account option , the opportunity and the account will be created sereperatly , I need to link this up. I found the section called Partner.  So I need to automatically force that Customer account to the agent account that he works for, so we can see reports

Comment: @smckitrick let me know if its still confusing

Comment: Forgive me, I need to plug in names for this to make sure that I am clear. Partner User (Bob) logs in. Bob works for (Bob's Company). Bob creates a new Account (Steve's Business). You want Bob's Company to appear in the Partner Related List under Steve's Business?

Comment: @smckitrick I am sorry I know this is confusing. So Steve's Bussiness is a brand new customer. Bob will create an account in our Community portal. under that account he will create contacts and opportunity.  Eventhough Bob Chose parent account in account as Steve's Bussiness, when you login in salesforce you will not be able to see Steves account under Bobs account, There for it seems like Bobs company has no account. Now if bob goes and Edits the Steve Bussiness account. then scrol down under Related List section , He clicks on Partners New. then he choses Bob's Company,

Comment: This new account now will show up under partner RelatedList in Salesforce for "Bobs Companys" Account. this was I can access it

Comment: @smckitrick Better Version. So "Steve's Bussiness" is a brand new customer. Bob will create New customer account  "Steve's Bussiness" in our Community portal. under that account he will create new contacts and  new opportunity.  When Bob Chooses parent account while creating new account as "Steve's Business", It will not show under "Bob's Company" , There for it seems like "Bobs company" hasnt created any new account. Now if bob goes and Edits "Steve Business" account ;While Editing scroll's down under Related List section , He clicks on Partners selects "New" then he choses ...

Comment: I think I got it now. The Parent Account field on the Account page layout has no association with the Partner Related List. Those are 2 completely different fields and functions. The Parent Account lets you set an account hierarchy, similar to an employee/manager reporting tree, where the new account has only 1 account directly above it. The Partner Related List lets you link multiple accounts to the new account, as each linked account could have a different role (supplier, shipping, warehousing, etc.).

Comment: I think I understand the scenario, so now I have a question about your actual question. You are asking to access or query the Partner Related List. Are you looking to make something happen automatically, looking to report on it, or looking for something else?

Comment: @smckitrick Right now Our internal staff wont see what bobs company has created, eventho Bob has selected Steve'sCompany as achild of that company when creating it. So what I want to do is When bob's login to our community portal, any new account that he makes, Automatically being forced to create new Partner related List the system assigns it to "Bob's Company" this way our internal staff can see what Bob's company has done so far.  I may be doing it wrong and perhaps there is some other way to do this, but this is the only way I have came up. Salesforce should have made it easier.

Comment: Take a look at the answer section and let me know if that helps you get what you need.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29986/discussion-between-bez-and-smckitrick).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a trigger that can link the Partner's Account with the new created account. I am not sure what the User Type is for the Partner User, so you may need to modify that to match your needs.

This trigger assumes that the Partner User's email address is the same as what is on their Contact Record.

```
trigger CreateAccountPartner on Account (after insert) {

if (UserInfo.getUserType() == 'PowerPartner'){


    List<Partner> AccPartner = new List<Partner>();
    List<String> UserEmail = new List<String>();
    List<ID> UserAccount = new List<ID>();

    for (Account acc : Trigger.new) {
        UserEmail.add(UserInfo.getUserEmail());
    }

    for (Contact con : [select id, accountid from Contact where email in :UserEmail]) {
        UserAccount.add(con.Accountid);
    }    

    for (Account AccNew : Trigger.new) {

            Partner p = new Partner();
            p.AccountFromId = AccNew.Id;
            p.AccountToId = UserAccount[0];
            p.Role = 'Dealer';

            AccPartner.add(p); // For Bulk processing of the Records.



    } // End of For
    // Inserting the New Partner Records
    insert AccPartner;
}
}
```